# JavaScript link onclick

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am trying to create a JavaScript link `onclick`.

My html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  xml:lang="da" lang="da" >
<head>

      <script type="text/javascript" >

var 22 = 'http://www.google.com';
function www(url) { window.open(url); }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<img style="width: 468px; height: 60px; border: 0pt none;" src="http://dk.orvillemedia.com/ads/banners/386/468x60.jpg" onclick="javascript:www(22);" alt="468x60">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identifiers cannot start with numbers.

`var 22 = 'http://www.google.com';` is an error.

`www(22)` passes a Number, not a variable.

Comment: can it be www(dasdasd-sadasda-asdasd) instead of a number

Comment: @Beginner: Have you read a tutorial at all? How about doing so? E.g. here about variables: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values%2c_Variables%2c_and_Literals#Variables

Answer (score 0):

Variables cannot start with a number in JavaScript.

```
var google = 'http://www.google.com';
```

and

```
onclick="www(google);"
```

will work.

This will make the code work, but if you are going to write more JavaScript code, I suggest you read the [*MDC JavaScript Guide*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) and [*quirksmode.org - Introducation to Events*](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) first.